# httpd proxy Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, vhosts

I got these errors

```
The proxy server could not handle the request
Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server
```

with this config but I replaced many option I can but still got same errors

vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.org
  ProxyRequests Off
<Location />
  ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

vhosts-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName wiki.bakji.kr
    SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass / https://localhost:3000
  ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3000
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

how can I fix this..?

Comment: Is your node.js server configured to serve over https ? Just use only `http://localhost` even in the `vhosts-le-ssl.conf`

Comment: nodejs only serves http so..

Comment: And its properly configured with a valid non self singed certificate ? Can you connect directly to the node server over https for test purpose ?

Comment: I can't directly connect nodejs with https(http work) also it's signed by letsencrypt..

Comment: Dont you think a litle bit more information would be helpful beside "I can't directly connect"  if I want to help ?!; Also why the need for tls on localhost ?

Comment: before I did same thing on httpd it's works only sets https on httpd not nodejs I never set ssl on nodejs before..I only open server with :3000 and proxy to https with httpd

Comment: localhost ->httpd(ssl)->user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223961/discussion-between-user12354454-and-marc).